# I got response from web service as byte how can i show it as pdf

Tags: android

"%PDF-1.4
                                                                                     %¢£
                                                                                     3 0 obj
                                                                                     <>
                                                                                     stream
                                                                                     ÿØÿà��JFIF����`��`����ÿá��¦Exif����MM��*��������>��������������V?��������������f��������������Q��������������Q������������.!Q������������.!������������z&�� ������ ����ú���� ����è�� ����u0�� ����ê`�� ����:�� ����p�� �� ����±ÿÛ��C��  $" &0P40,,0bFJ:Ptfzxrfpn¸®np Ú¢®¾ÄÎÐÎ|âòàÈð¸ÊÎÆÿÛ��C"$$0*0^44^ÆpÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÆÿÀ����)��k"��ÿÄ����������������������

Comment: Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just save the bytes to file.

Comment: @greenapps  thanks for the reply, I am trying to save it as file by creating new file which is .pdf file. But when i write this pdf file then same byte data get written in this file with 75 pages.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution of that..
thanks for the reply

```
           try{
                long lenghtOfFile = response.length;

                //covert reponse to input stream
                InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response);
                File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File file = new File(path, filename);
                map.put("resume_path", file.toString());
                BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();

                output.close();
                input.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
```